# Elastic Search With MongoDb

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-mvc, elasticsearch

I am very new to Elastic Search so i have gone thorugh many articles and blog to implement elastic search in java with mongodb but can not find a satisfactory answer.

scenario : I have a DB of mongodb and the collection is saved like

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("59775731409eb01e28d971dd"), 
    "sympid" : "5", 
    "name" : "abnormal bleeding", 
    "related_keyword" : "abnormal bleeding||uncontrollable bleeding"
}
```

Now i have a task to make the search API in elastic search for now what i learnt is(i don't know whether i am correct)

> 1. Elastic Search have their own db
> 2. if you want to implement it in mongo you need to index the db (don't know how to do it)(need some river plugin but i guess it is only available for unix environment and not windows)
> 3. There is plugin to index it mongo in ES, (but not found any plugin for windows)

any one out there who implemented ES+Spring MVC+MongoDB in windows?

Comment: Elasticsearch is Database with Huge searching copabilities. It's not some build up on top of your DB. Hence, you can't "implement" it. You can do some (a lot of!) searching in Mongo but it has nothing to do with Elasticsearch

Answer (score 2):

In order to search your data with ElasticSearch, you need to first index it. 
There are various tools which allow you to load your data from MongoDB to ElasticSearch.

EDIT: I Implemented such ingestion with MongoDB, Spring and used ElasticSearch for hadoop to do so

EDIT2: I read of River and it should work for windows, it even has a windows batch file.

See: https://github.com/richardwilly98/elasticsearch-river-mongodb, https://github.com/mongodb-labs/mongo-connector/wiki,https://github.com/compose/transporter

Reference: https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/5-way-sync-data-from-mongodb-es-kai-hao